# Message: default backend - 404 (selenium - python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to start a selenium application (with python) via `webdriver.Remote()`, like they recomends [on documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-with-remote-webdriver), but when I run the code below, I get the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: default backend - 404
```

My code is here:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.set_capability("platformName", "LINUX")
chrome_options.set_capability("browserName", "chrome")

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

prefs = {"download.default_directory": 'downloads'}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=chrome_options.to_capabilities()
)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('stackoverflow')
search_box.submit()
driver.quit()
```

I've already tried to remove the options and use only the recommended code, as below, but I got the same problem.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('stackoverflow')
search_box.submit()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem and it is related to `command_executor`. Whenever you need to declare this argument, don't put `http` or `https` before the address. So the correct code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.set_capability("platformName", "LINUX")
chrome_options.set_capability("browserName", "chrome")

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

prefs = {"download.default_directory": 'downloads'}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=chrome_options.to_capabilities()
)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('stackoverflow')
search_box.submit()
driver.quit()
```

Or the simpler code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('stackoverflow')
search_box.submit()
driver.quit()
```